# Ошибка в запросе к БД SQLite, с поиском заданном с помощью LIKE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь составить запрос к БД с поиском по номеру телефона с 10 последними цифрами, но на ниже представленном запросе приложение вылетает, не подскажите в чём ошибка?

`DBHelper`-имя БД

`TABLE_MESSAGE` -имя таблицы

`MESS_PHONE` - один из столбцов в таблице

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.danil.smssecurity, PID:
>   1760 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.danil.smssecurity/com.example.danil.smssecurity.Acrans.Acr.acran2_2}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1
>   because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

```
 Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_MESSAGE, new String[] {"_id", DBHelper.MESS_PHONE}, DBHelper.MESS_PHONE + " LIKE '?'" , new String[] {"%"+searchNomer}, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Уберите одинарные кавычки вокруг `?`.